# error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter

Tags: c#, unity3d

ошибка при добавлении 2 и более параметров в функцию в юнити.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TEST : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
      DDD();
    }
    void DDD(float sss, Vector2 aaa){
      Debug.Log("ddd");
    }
}
```

этот код выдает ошибку:

```
Assets\Scripts\TEST.cs(16,7): error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'sss' of 'TEST.DDD(float, Vector2)'
```

Comment: При вызове функции, функция ожидает параметров в себе.

Comment: О чём и говорит ошибка: `Не приведен аргумент, соответствующий требуемому формальному параметру`

Comment: спасибо, помогло

Answer (score -2):

```
void DDD(float sss = 3f, Vector2 aaa = default(Vector2)){
  Debug.Log("ddd");
}
```

Comment: Старайтесь полностью описывать решение, чтобы для других пользователей было понятно, почему этот вариант будет работать.

Comment: `default(Vector2)` = `Vector2.zero`